# The vertical alignment shown in the preview for uploaded images is not the same used for the post

Tags: bug, design

The vertical alignment shown in the preview of a post is different from the effective alignment used when the post is save.

[image: preview]

[image: post]

In the preview, the image is shown higher than it is effectively shown when the post is saved. They should be the same.